Docker container is not started due to error: DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value on my Django application
Docker container is not started due to error: DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value on my Django application.
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '*name*',
        'HOST': '*host*',
        'USER': '*user*',
        'PASSWORD': '*password*'
    }
}

I use Docker container in Azure with postgresql database. Can anyone help solving the problem?
please tell me if you need more information.
Thank you!
When I run my application locally my application is working with my production database connected, so that shows that code in application should work and error is in Azure? Right?
